# Java swixml in an OSX app bundle

Tags: java, xml, macos, bundle, swixml

I'm developing an application in Java and have gotten it rolled into an app bundle, but I'm having issues with the xml file for building my Gui. I would like to store the xml file inside the app bundle, but the only way I've been able to get it to work is to directly access the file Application.app/Contents/Resources/Java/Gui.xml . This obviously breaks if the application is renamed, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the WorkingDirectory property in the App's Info.plist..

http://www.blog.jasonederle.com/?p=15